MIIS deletes Microsoft 365 accounts upon moving users between different OUs in a local Active Directory
We use a local Active Directory for domain and a Microsoft Office 365 subscription for emails. And we have MIIS to sync them.
I noticed that when I move a user from an OU to another in the local AD, the user loses Microsoft 365 licence, and his email account stops working.
On investigation and asking, I found some records in the MIIS client about those moved users. I looks like MIIS is somehow configured to delete the Microsoft account when a user is moved.
Can someone guide me to correct this fatal mistake?


Rerun the Entra ID Connect wizard and check your Domain and OU filtering config (it has a check in the target OU)

Those OUs were newly created and not checked in Azure AD Connect to be synced. I've checked them.
